# Setting specific humidity vertical profile in an LES

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere-modelling, simulation, planetary-boundary-layer

I am working with an LES (Large-Eddy Simulation) model, and I want to define the vertical profile of specific humidity (qt) based on a given temperature profile (thl). However, I am not sure how to calculate the specific humidity lapse rates that correspond to the temperature profile I set.

My aim is to see the onset of clouds in my domain therefore my diagnostics are liquid water content, liquid water path and cloud fraction. I have tested so far a linearly stratified potential temperature profile and I see how it changes throughout the simulation run with an amount of sensible heat flux and moisture from the ground(figure).

[image]

I want to perform a sensitivity run and check my diagnostics while I change the initial potential temperature profile (stable, neutral and unstable). However, I am not sure how to change the corresponding moisture profile for each case.

e.g. Keeping a relatively low RH throughout the profile (<50%), how will the moisture profile change with regards to temperature?